# How to trigger a button tap with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to automatically trigger a tap on a button with javascript.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementsByName('name');
```

I tried the following and none of them worked.

```
submitButton.click();
```

and

```
const touchEvent = new TouchEvent("touchstart", {
    touches: [touch],
    view: window,
    cancelable: true,
    bubbles: true,
});
submitButton.dispatchEvent(touchEvent);
```

Neither worked.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What code is expected to run when the button is clicked?

Comment: how about `var submitButton = document.getElementsByName('name')[0]` ?

Comment: what does your html code look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 0):

[`Document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a `NodeList` of elements (not a single element).

As far as the event, `click` should work just fine:

```js
for (const elm of document.getElementsByTagName('button')) {
  elm.addEventListener('click', (ev) => console.log(ev.target.textContent));
}

const buttons = document.getElementsByName('name');

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.click();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button name="name">one</button>
  <button name="name">two</button>
  <button>three</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the above button with a onClick function.
Change the

```
document.getElementsByName('name')
```

to

```
document.getElementById('id')
```

Full Code:

Html:

```
<button id="btn" onClick="clicked()">
Click me
</button>
```

JS:

```
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
btn.click();

function clicked() {
    console.log("Clicked");
}
```

If you want to trigger multiple buttons with same class:

Html:

```
<button class="btn" onClick="clicked()">
Click me
</button>
```

JS:

```
var btn=document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
btn[0].click();

function clicked() {
    console.log("Clicked");
}
```

For multiple button with same class, the return of the document.getElementsByClassName will return an array of object. In the above example, I have used the first element of that array, but if you want, you can loop through the array and trigger the click event.

Answer (score 0):

[`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a `NodeList` Collection of elements with a given name attribute in the document.

So your `submitButton` will be an array. So you have to dispatch the click event with `submitButton[0].click()`

```js
var submitButton = document.getElementsByName('name');
submitButton[0].click();
function submitClick() {
  console.log('submitClick')
}
```

```html
<button name="name" onclick="submitClick()">Submit</button>
```